# Authenticating Moodle using phpldapadmin server

Tags: moodle, openldap, phpldapadmin

I'm using Moodle 2.7,i have enabled LDAP authentication for users.I have a phpldapadmin(openldap) server which with DNS as cn=admin,dc=demoldap,dc=org and i have created many users accounts in the DN.

when i tried to login with those user account in moodle im getting the following error

```
"The user account "user1" is not available on this site"
```

but i have account for user1 in openldap.please help me to solve this issue.where should i create my user account in my server? and how to authenticate in moodle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that "Prevent account creation when authenticating (authpreventaccountcreation)" option on "Manage authentication: page is set to **false** (new accounts are permitted).

But if you get this error on users, that already present in moodle, - check LDAP authentication plugin settings.